# Reason for KeyNotFoundException in Dictionary initialization

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, ienumerable

The following code

```
new Dictionary<string, List<int>> {
    ["a"] = {1},
};
```

Throws a run-time `KeyNotFoundException`, albeit that {1} is a perfectly well-formed array (i.e. `int[] a = {1,2,3,4}` being valid code). Changing the `TValue` of the `Dictionary` to `int[]`, throws a compile-time `CS1061`, but this does not (note the added `new[]` array-allocation):

```
new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>> {
    ["a"] = new[]{1},
};
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Please ask *one* question per post. I've answered the first part of your question - I would encourage you to delete the second part, and ask it in a new question if you really can't find the answer elsewhere. (Fundamentally, `int[] ar = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }` is an *array-initializer*, which can only be used in declarations of array variables.)

Comment: Done, thanks again.

Comment: The resolution of the first issue is `["a"] =  new List<int> { 1 },`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your first piece of code is using a collection initializer, which doesn't use logical assignment, but instead is intended to call `Add` on an *existing* collection. In other words, this:

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, List<int>> {
    ["a"] = {1},
};
```

is equivalent to:

```
var tmp = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
var list = tmp["a"];
list.Add(1);
var x = tmp;
```

Hopefully it's obvious from that why the second line of the expansion would throw an exception.

Part of your error in reasoning is:

> albeit that {1} is a perfectly well-formed array

No, it's not. The syntax `{1}` means different things in different contexts. In this case, it's a collection initializer. In the statement:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

it's an array initializer. That syntax *only* creates a new array in an array declaration, or as part of an array creation expression, e.g. `new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and comprehensive response! I think we're a bit too focused in our C++ ways, because we couldn't *quite* put our finger on what's happening here.

Comment: Jon, you are right for the collection initializer, but why it translates this way? Isn't collection initializer supposed to work only with `new SomeCollection { ... }`?

Comment: @IvanStoev: Nope, it can be nested within an object initializer - that can be really handy, too.